# How to have only a few selectable text elements on a webpage in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a webpage where only a few text elements can be selected.
With every browser - except Internet Explorer - you can only select the appropriate text elements (Text selectable) and the input field (Input Field), what's great. But with Internet Explorer you can select the whole page if you start the selection at 'Text selectable'.

Is there a way to prevent this undesirable behavior in Internet Explorer?

And here's my code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style type = "text/css">
      body {
        user-select:           none;
        -khtml-user-select:    none;
        -moz-user-select:      none;
        -ms-user-select:       none;
        -webkit-user-select:   none;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      }
        div.selectable {
        user-select:           text;
        -khtml-user-select:    text;
        -moz-user-select:      text;
        -ms-user-select:       text;
        -webkit-user-select:   text;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Text not selectable<br>
    <div class = "selectable">Text selectable</div>
    Text not selectable<br>
    <div class = "selectable">Text selectable</div>
    <input type = "text" value = "Input Field">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a known issue with the Internet Explorer browser.

I try to make several tests but IE can select the nonselectable text if the selection starts from the selectable text.

Also in any browser, web page text can be copied using many ways like copying the text from the source code, or by downloading the HTML file.

So it will not possible for you to prevent copying the text in every way.

I found a code that can just give the effect to the text that it is not selected.

```
body::selection 
{ 
     background: transparent;
         
}
```

Modified code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <style type = "text/css">
      body {
        user-select:           none;
        -khtml-user-select:    none;
        -moz-user-select:      none;
        -ms-user-select:       none;
        -webkit-user-select:   none;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      }
body::selection 
{ 
     background: transparent;
         
}
        div.selectable {
        user-select:           text;
        -khtml-user-select:    text;
        -moz-user-select:      text;
        -ms-user-select:       text;
        -webkit-user-select:   text;
      }
    


    </style>
  </head>
  <body >
    
    Text not selectable<br>  
        <div class = "selectable" >Text selectable</div>
    Text not selectable<br>
        <div class = "selectable">Text selectable</div>

    <input type = "text" value = "Input Field">
  </body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

But if you copy and try to paste it then you can notice that nonselectable text is also there.

So for the IE browser, I did not get any way that can prevent copying the nonselectable text if selection start from the selectable element.

AS a workaround specifically for the IE browser, you can prevent users from copying any text on the web page to avoid this issue.

Comment: So it looks like this is a bug in Internet Explorer. But your workaround is pretty nice. Many thanks.
Unfortunately your workaround doesn't work for the input field, which still can visibly be selected.
I'm also surprised that Ctrl+A doesn't work in Internet Explorer, because it works in any other browser.